# How to print Api response data as collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to print API response data as collection on blade for that i have used following line

```
$customers =   collect(json_decode($response, true));
```

But whenever i tried to print with following code:

```
 @foreach($customers as $row)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$row->first_name}} {{$row->last_name}}</td>
      <td>{{$row->email}}</td>
      <td>{{$row->phone}}</td>
      <td>{{$row->addresses['country_name']}}</td>
    </tr>
```

```
  @endforeach
```

it shows bellow error, What's the problem here?

> Attempt to read property "first_name" on array

Here is the  API response:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#341 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\IntegrationController.php:61
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "customers" => array:3 [▼
      0 => array:27 [▼
        "id" => 6895839936762
        "email" => "russel.winfield@example.com"
        "accepts_marketing" => false
        "created_at" => "2023-10-20T11:06:26-04:00"
        "updated_at" => "2023-10-20T11:06:26-04:00"
        "first_name" => "Russell"
        "last_name" => "Winfield"
        "orders_count" => 0
        "state" => "disabled"
        "total_spent" => "0.00"
        "last_order_id" => null
        "note" => "This customer is created with most available fields"
        "verified_email" => true
        "multipass_identifier" => null
        "tax_exempt" => false
        "tags" => "VIP"
        "last_order_name" => null
        "currency" => "USD"
        "phone" => "+16135550135"
        "addresses" => array:1 [▶]
        "accepts_marketing_updated_at" => "2023-10-20T11:06:26-04:00"
        "marketing_opt_in_level" => null
        "tax_exemptions" => []
        "email_marketing_consent" => array:3 [▶]
        "sms_marketing_consent" => array:4 [▶]
        "admin_graphql_api_id" => "gid://shopify/Customer/6895839936762"
        "default_address" => array:17 [▶]
      ]
      1 => array:26 [▶]
      2 => array:26 [▶]
    ]
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

Comment: Delete true from json_decode

Comment: Please keep in mind that Laravel 5 is EOL since nearly four years. Please update your application to avoid that you are running in any bug that was fixed in the meantime

Comment: "*Here is the API response*" - do you mean that is `$response`?  If yes, you can see it is already a Collection, there is no need to `collect(json_decode());` it.  Or do you mean the dump you've shown is `$customers`?

Comment: best practice for this case is to use DTO pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reality, $row is an associative array, but you are using it like an object. Instead of using object notation to access its elements, you should use array notation. Change your code as follows:

```
@foreach($customers['customers'] as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$row['first_name']}} {{$row['last_name']}}</td>
        <td>{{$row['email']}}</td>
        <td>{{$row['phone']}}</td>
        <td>
            @foreach($row['addresses'] as $address)
                {{$address['country_name']}}
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: country_name inside address array. How do i print that?

Comment: I have made updates to my answer.